# How can i add images to a picturebox using VB?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to create an image viewer that will load an unlimited number images to a form. Could someone please help me with this?
Here is the code. 
there is a button named loadImagesBttn and the picture box named myImage

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub loadImagesBttn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles loadImagesBttn.Click
        Dim dlg As New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
        dlg.FileName = "Image" 'Default image file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg" 'Default extention 
        dlg.Filter = "Images (.jpg)| *.jpg " 'Filter images my extension

        'Show open file dialog box 
        Dim result? As Boolean = dlg.ShowDialog()

        'Process open file dialog box results 
        If result = True Then
            'Open image 
            Dim selectedImage As String = dlg.FileName

            myImage.Source = 'this is where I get confused.

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Are you wanting the user to have to open the file dialog everytime they want a different image, or are you wanting them to select multiple files in the file dialog and have the picturebox be able to display them all individually or at the same time?

Comment: I want them all to display at the same time. And have and have some sort of an image library

Comment: Then you're either going to have to create a lot of little picture boxes and assign the images to said picture boxes and add them all to something like a FlowLayoutPanel, or you are going to create a custom graphics object to draw out all of the images in some sort of grid and then use that generated image to back the picturebox.

Comment: That looks a little complicated for me at the moment but I will research on it. Could you help me do that then I can learn from your source code? I would really appreciate Brandon

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the file:

```
myImage.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri(selectedImage))
```

Comment: Currently my default file extension is .jpg
I cant seem to load any JPG images when I open the dialogbox :(

Comment: That worked. Now I need to figure out how I could load an unlimited number of images and preview all at once in the form.